Sudo user flag is not using the designated user
When I attempt to use a sudo command with the -u flag to use an account with the correct privileges, the command will not change users:
<logged-in-user>@<host>:~$sudo -u <admin-user> [command]
[sudo] password for <logged-in-user>:

is what happens every time when I thought the -u flag should force it to ask for <admin-user> password.
I have this workstation AD-joined and the admin AD group set in /etc/sudoers
If any other info is needed, please let me know, this is my first time posting on here.

"when I know the -u flag should force it to ask for <admin-user> password" – How do you know? Is any option mentioned here in use? Please [edit] the question.

sudo -u <admin-user> will NOT require <admin-user> password - I mean <admin-user> doesn't even need to be a sudoer, so why would you need to use that users password?

Is it possible you misunderstand the SUDO command? What are you trying to do using SUDO? Are you perhaps trying to do SU instead?

Sorry for the delay here and the lack of clarity - I'm still learning the nuances of Linux administration through self-teaching.  What I am trying to accomplish is to allow a member of the admin AD group to enter their password on a sudo command when on a standard user's account. If this is accomplished in another way, I can't seem to find it online.

-u doesn't do this. Its purpose is to specify which user you want to become after passing the authentication check.
The simplest method to achieve what you want would be in two steps:

Have the normal user run su <admin> to switch to the admin user (with access controlled by the target user's password).

Once switched to the admin user, run sudo whatever to run the specified command as the 'root' user (with access controlled by /etc/sudoers).


It is possible to configure sudo to ask for the target account's password rather than the invoker's (returning to somewhat a 'su'-like model), but that would still require the aforementioned two steps – first a sudo -u admin to switch from normal user to the admin user, and a second sudo to finally switch from the admin user to root – and it would require very fragile /etc/sudoers configuration, while su can achieve the same by default.

What I am trying to accomplish is to allow a member of the admin AD group to enter their password on a sudo command when on a standard user's account

Generally, sudo doesn't behave this way. Its design is all about granting access directly to the invoker's account without relying on the knowledge of some other administrator's password; in fact that is the primary feature that distinguishes sudo from the traditional su (with which, knowledge of the root password is what grants access).
Note that the overall architecture of admin access in Linux is rather different from Windows. When an admin runs sudo apt install something, that doesn't run the command as "Vorton but elevated" – instead it runs the command specifically as the root user (which is the only account that inherently has special rights).
And since the entire functionality of sudo is already about switching users, the purpose of the -u option is to specify the target user that you want to become instead of root. It can't be the option to borrow another user's "sudo" privileges, because the ability to borrow another user's privileges is in itself what's being controlled by sudo.

If you're looking for something closer to Windows UAC, that would be the PolicyKit system – which is mainly found in desktop environments, but can exist also on servers.
Unlike sudo, polkit does have the concept of "administrator" accounts which are directly allowed to perform certain tasks; and if the invoking user doesn't have some permission and is not an admin, then polkit will automatically prompt for an admin's password instead.
You can see it in action when trying to systemctl start something (without sudo), or by running pkexec to get a privileged shell (i.e. a shell as 'root') – assuming your distribution hasn't removed pkexec in panic last year, anyway; if they have, then systemd's new run0 or the slightly older systemd-run -S would give similar results.

Thank you for the detailed explanation! I will look into these alternate options for admin control.

You could first become the <admin-user> by entering the following command.
su <admin-user>

You will be asked for the password of the <admin-user>. You can now use sudo command. If prompted for a password, enter the password for the <admin-user>. If you want to become the root user, so to avoid having to enter sudo, the enter the following after becoming the <admin-user>.
sudo su

When finished being the root user or <admin-user>, enter the exit command.

Update:
I suppose you could define the following function, which would allow entering a command as a root user from a single line.
sa() { su -c "sudo $(shift;printf "%q " "$@")" -P "$1"; }

You probably would want to add the above line to the end of your ~/.bashrc file. This would avoid having to manually enter the funtion.
With above function defined, you could do the following. Here you would have to enter password for the <admin-user> twice.
<logged-in-user>@<host>:~$sa <admin-user> [command]
Password:
[sudo] password for <logged-in-user>:

For example, to become the root user, you would enter the following.
<logged-in-user>@<host>:~$sa <admin-user> su
Password:
[sudo] password for <logged-in-user>:

