Separate password for sudo
On my Kubuntu, I have two users: non-sudoer "usual" and sudoer "admin". The latter is allowed to use sudo when this user is logged in. The former cannot use sudo when they're logged in, so I have to first su admin and then I can use sudo and provide admin's password. I want to make it possible to provide admin's password when I'm using sudo under usual.
I tried sudo -u admin somecommand, but it still asks for usual's password. I tried adding Defaults:usual targetpw from this answer to sudoers file, and:

for sudo somecommand it asks for root's password which is not what I need;
for sudo -u admin comecommand it does ask for admin's password, but then it says usual is not in sudoers file.

How do I make sudo somecommand ask for admin's password by default? Preferably without -u admin, if that's possible.
If you're wondering, why am I doing this at all, I am trying to mimic what polkit does when I'm doing something in GUI. Since usual is not an administrator password, polkit asks for admin's password and lets me enter it and perform the action I needed. This is kind of similar to UAC in Windows when logged under non-administrator account: it asks for administrator account's password.
Edit: There was a similar question suggested in the comments. However, I think I should explain the global scope of what I'm trying to achieve. I want my login password to be different from my sudo password. When I was using Windows, creating a separate administrator account made this possible. On Kubuntu, authentication is different, so this approach might not help at all. Previous paragraph on 'why I am doing this at all' refers to my idea to create a separate admin user to mimic Windows setup, but now I think I should try a different approach. I found this question on how to do this, and I am currently looking into trying out ways to do this described in the answers. I should mention that I want to try something different from just using root's password as a separate password.

I believe I've already answered exactly this question last month: https://superuser.com/questions/1860473/sudo-user-flag-is-not-using-the-designated-user/1860910#1860910

This question is similar to: Sudo user flag is not using the designated user. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
